# How to synchronize the uncommitted code of another computer?

Tags: git, github, remote-access

I have two computers(computer 1 and computer 2), one at work and one at home.

Both computers are connected to the same Github repository.

I forgot to commit the code after writing in computer 1. Now I'm using computer 2 and I want to get the uncommitted code in computer 1 so I can synchronize the content by committing the code in computer 1 first, and then start writing code in computer 2. Is there's a way I can do that?

Comment: git won't help you with that. Use RDP or SSH or whatever to access computer1.

Comment: git *works* across networks. It isn't actually a network itself. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The way the workflows usually goes is that you pull new commits from the github repository, write some code, commit it, and then push the commits to the github repository. At no point is github able *by itself* to go and fetch directly data on any computer: you need to push it. (*think about it*: if github could read from your computer data that you haven't decided to send, this would be a major security problem).

Your best bet is to connect to computer 1 via remote desktop protocols or SSH, commit and push your code there.

Alternatively, if you plan to work on parts of the project that are not exactly located in the same place as your uncommitted work, just work and commit from computer 2, and pull from computer 1 when you come back to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you can remote in to your pc at work, do so. Then commit and push the code yourself. Or you might create something like this next time in case you forgot to commit/push your codes, let's say on a temp branch.

[how to automate the "commit-and-push" process? (git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709404/how-to-automate-the-commit-and-push-process-git)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is maybe using tools like [sycthing](https://syncthing.net/) to sync these two project folders

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).